# Querying a .csv file with conditions using Pandas and .shift

Tags: python, pandas, csv, conditional-statements, querying

I'm having trouble querying a simple .csv file of trade data with conditions. The .csv file has 5 columns - `[open, high, low, close, volume]` with a **time-series index, of minute by minute trades**.

What I want to do is build a script that

> (1) tells me how many times the close price minus the open price of
>   the previous minute is positive.
>
> (2) the volume of the previous minute is greater than that of the
>   minute before it.

So far I have the first half (1) down with:

```
ts2 = ts[(ts["close"]-ts["open"].shift(1))>0]
```

However, I am having trouble combining it with the volume conditions (2) I require. I have attempted the following, both resulting in syntax and other errors.

```
ts2 = ts[(ts["close"]-ts["open"].shift(1))>0]
ts3 = ts[(ts["volume"].shift(1)-ts["volume"].shift(2))>0]
ts4 = ts[ts2 & ts3]

ts4 = ts[(ts["close"]-ts["open"].shift(1)>0) & (ts["volume"].shift(1)-ts["volume"].shift(2)>0)
```

Ultimately I would use the:

```
print(len(ts4))
```

To find how many occurrences there are in my csv file of the conditional query.

Please let me know how I can combine both conditions, and if there is a way to improve my current methodology.

Thank you, all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just make `ts2` and `ts3` masks instead of actual queried dataframe.

```
ts2 = (ts["close"] - ts["open"].shift(1)) > 0  #this is a mask
ts3 = (ts["volume"].shift(1) - ts["volume"].shift(2)) > 0 #this is a mask
ts4 = ts.loc[ts2 & ts3] #query using 2 masks
```

Hope this helps.